# Headings don't show the content correctly

Tags: table-of-contents, header-footer, fancyhdr, double-sided, tufte

This code:

```
\documentclass[twoside,symmetric,notoc,justified]{tufte-book}%

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[latin]{babel}
\usepackage[OT1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lipsum}


\geometry{
  %showframe,
  paperwidth=145mm,
  paperheight=215mm,
  inner=16mm,
  outer=10mm,
  top=10mm,
  bottom=40mm,
  marginparsep=3mm,
  marginparwidth=40mm,
  includemp,
  includehead,
}
\fancyhf{}%
\fancyhead[LE]{\bfseries\thepage\quad$\bigg|$\quad\leftmark}
\fancyhead[RO]{\bfseries\rightmark\quad$\bigg|$\quad\thepage}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter*{Introduction}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\textbf{Introduction}}
\lipsum[1-5]

\chapter{Chapter1}
\section{Section1}
\lipsum
\section{Section2}
\lipsum
\section{Section3}
\lipsum
\chapter{Chapter2}
\section{Section4}
\lipsum
\section{Section5}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

gives this:
[image]

As you see, the headings still show "Index", but it is already "Introduction". How to fix it? I want it to show "Introduction" on the page where it is. Thank you.

Comment: This is because you are using `\chapter*`. You can either remove the `*` or write `\chapter*{Introduction}
\markboth{Introduction}{Introduction}`.

Comment: In addition to @marmot's comment, you can also remove the `\addcontentsline` if you remove the asterisk. `\chapter*` suppressing adding the chapter to the TOC.

Comment: Just two more things. First, I don't think the title of your question is appropriate because it does show correctly, and second I agree with @godbyk.

Comment: I added '\markboth{Introduction}{Introduction}' and it worked. Thank you. I cannot remove asterisk because I don't want to enumerate Introduction as a separate chapter/section.